# What are the rules/recommendations around changing someone’s spell casting stat?

Tags: dnd-5e

Each magic class seems to have a stat associated with it (Int, Wis, or Cha), used to determine stats such as spell save difficulty class, or the power of certain abilities that the class has.

I think sorcerers and warlocks use Charisma.
I understand how Charisma might translate to power for most warlocks *(as they would be able to strike a pact with their patron and convince it that they are on track with their task more easily)*, but what if they made a pact with someone who doesn’t care about how their servants present themselves, but has faith in those with a high intelligence (or wisdom).

If you wanted to create a sorcerer or warlock who’s character traits make them bad at social situations, but great at their craft *(or the other way around)*, then I’d expect this would be done by requesting to use your preferred stat instead of Charisma for your spell casting modifier, spell save difficulty class, and any other Charisma calculation that’s directly part of your class abilities *(or possibly JUST your spell casting modifier and spell save DC if you wanted to make a more mixed character)*. How would various dungeon masters respond to this sort of request, and how would you recommend someone respond to that sort of request if they were a dungeon master?

Basically:

- Are there any rules that allow players to change the stat that represents someone’s spell casting ability? *(They don’t necessarily have to be official)*
- Does the ability to do so unbalance the game in any way? *(This is about changing the magic stat for a (few) specific character(s), not everyone of a class)*

*(...also, why would charisma be important to a sorcerer?)*

Comment: Related: [What are the possible balance implications for houseruling INT as Paladin's spellcasting ability and class features?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156103/14878), [What are the impacts of changing a Ranger's spellcasting ability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128756/14878) and [What is the reasoning behind having sorcerers' and warlocks' spells rely on charisma?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106437/14878)

Comment: On the Sorcerer question: [Why do Sorcerers use Charisma?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/why-do-sorcerers-use-charisma)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.